# Facebook PHP SDK - Get user name and profile picture of my app users without requiring facebook connect

Tags: php, facebook

First of all, thanks in advance for reading. I've already posted this question in the facebook forums but after a couple of hours I'm not getting any responses.

I've got this app where an user can choose a piece (like in a puzzle). After the user picks a piece, he is redirected to the facebook authorize page and then returned to the app, then I save the user ID and his chosen piece in the database. At this point I've got everything alright... but the problem comes when...

If anyone see the app, he should be able to see the pieces and the PIECES OWNER INFO (name and profile picture).

The problem is if the user has not allowed the app yet (facebook authorization page), I can't use the facebook API to get the users who have already allowed the app (because I need an access token and the access token is given only to users who has authorized the app).

So, in short:

I need: get name and profile picture of users who have already authorized the app, without authenticating all users.

P.S: I was trying the "Authenticating as an App" option with PHP+libCURL but didn't work (or I did it the wrong way).

P.S2: Sorry if I have writing mistakes, my speaking language is spanish.

Thanks again... A LOT!!!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No authentication nor breach of TOS required if you have the IDs, as [profile pic and name are public information](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/)

Proof?? [Right Here in this JSON](https://graph.facebook.com/4).

Comment: oh my god!!!! thanks a lot, I haven't slept for a week or so and can't even see the simple things like these... THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!!

Comment: As of now, your proof's broken.

Comment: in this very moment, your JSON is not producing picture url

Comment: welp, looks like that feature was taken out. fml, why doesnt facebook tell us in their docs how to do this.....